# Du wirst eliminiert > You will eliminate? Is this a mistake?

Tags: translation, german-to-english, passive

As far as I know, subject + werden + participle is the template for passive voice.

So, I put "Du wirst eliminiert" in Google Translate and it suggests "You will eliminate".

[image]

If I click the translation, an alternative "You are eliminated" is to be found — what I expected as the correct translation.

Is "You will eliminate" ever correct in any context?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I cannot reproduce it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say "You will be eliminated" or "You are being eliminated". Here is definitely passive voice. German doesn't have a continuous tense and the presence tense is often used to describe the near future.

I don't know the context, but I wouldn't use the word "eliminieren" at all, except maybe describing the Terminator film.